# OpenERP - Suggestions not showing in dropdown box

Tags: odoo

Under Sales/Products/Products in OpenERP I have a new field Item Class, which is a dropdown box. When typing a word in the box, the suggestions, i.e. items containing the word I typed, are not shown inside the box. What is shown is only "Create and Edit...". I expect suggestions to be shown, each containing the word I initially typed in the dropdown box.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What happens when you open the dropdown box? Can you see the items? For me this functionality is working just fine in Openerp 6.0...

Comment: May be you can show us some code...

Comment: Check the name_search() method of the Item Class object.

Comment: When I click on the arrow (right side of the dropdown box) it lists inside the box the items. However, when I type something in drop down, it does not show any matching suggestions, it shows o0nly "Create and Edit...". I don't have any code for that. Amother dropdown box in another view shows the suggestions as I type. I will try name_search. Thank you.

Comment: The name_search() worked. Thank you Quentin and thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the name_search() method of the Item Class object. –  Quentin THEURET 2 days ago